# Exclude some apps from "close all"

Tags: applications, sony-xperia, 8.0-oreo, force-close

Is there a way to exclude some apps from "close all"?

I sometimes have many apps open on my device and want to quit them all except Spotify (for example) because I am listening to music while doing that. Spotify in this example could be "force closed" manually, not with the other apps (as default now) .

*Edit*

Device: Sony Xperia XA1

OS: 8.0.0

"close all" option is seen when clicking the right key on lower status bar

Reason why I'd like to close apps: I have a battery issue, and if I leave my most-used apps in background, it negatively affects battery life on my device

Comment: Also,*why* do you want to close other apps (barring Spotify)?

Comment: Have you tried the feature mentioned [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-make-use-of-the-android-nougat-recent-apps-lock/)? It kind of prevents an app being swiped  from recent apps list too.